# How can I determine the amount of movement a mouse is allowed between two click for the WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK message to be fired?

Tags: windows, winapi, wndproc

How can I determine the amount of movement a mouse is allowed between two click for the WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK message to be fired?

[MSDN Receiving Double-Click Messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa931259.aspx)

> The OS generates a double-click message when the user clicks a mouse
>   button twice in quick succession. When the user clicks a button, the
>   OS establishes a rectangle centered on the hot spot of the cursor. The
>   OS also marks the time at which the click occurred. When the user
>   clicks the same button a second time, the OS determines whether the
>   **hot spot is still within the rectangle** and calculates the time elapsed
>   since the first click. If the hot spot is still within the rectangle
>   and the elapsed time does not exceed the time-out value for a
>   double-click, the OS generates a double-click message. An application
>   can retrieve the time-out value for a double-click by using the
>   GetDoubleClickTime function.

I am able to determine the maximum allowed time interval [GetDoubleClickTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa922956.aspx) but would like to know the maximum of mouse moment allowed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the documentation for [GetSystemMetrics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The second click must occur within the rectangle that is defined by
>   SM_CXDOUBLECLK and SM_CYDOUBLECLK for the system to consider the two
>   clicks a double-click.

```
int x_limit = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXDOUBLECLK);
int y_limit = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYDOUBLECLK);
```